# How can we import user groups from Novell edirectory to liferay?

Tags: ldap, integration, liferay, novell

How can I import userGroups and users from Novel EDirectory to liferay?

Here are the Novel eDirectory Setup details:

```
Group :


   cn       group1
   member
                cn=user1,ou=ABCD,ou=ABC,o=AB
                cn=user2,ou=ABCD,ou=ABC,o=AB

    objectClass
                groupOfNames
                Top
```

User 1:

```
cn              user1
objectClass     inetOrgPerson
objectClass     ssDEFG
objectClass     abcUser
objectClass     organizationalPerson
objectClass     Person
objectClass     ndsLoginProperties
objectClass     Top
objectClass     DirXML-PasswordSyncStatusUser
objectClass     DirXML-ApplicationAttrs
sn              user1surname
groupMembership cn=group1,ou=DEFGH,ou=DEFG,ou=ABC,o=AB
groupMembership cn=group2,ou=COURSES,ou=ABC,o=AB
groupMembership cn=group3,ou=DEFGH,ou=DEFG,ou=ABC,o=AB
email                              test1@test.com
```

User 2:

```
cn              user2
objectClass     inetOrgPerson
objectClass     ssDEFG
objectClass     abcUser
objectClass     organizationalPerson
objectClass     Person
objectClass     ndsLoginProperties
objectClass     Top
objectClass     DirXML-PasswordSyncStatusUser
objectClass     DirXML-ApplicationAttrs
sn              user2surname
groupMembership cn=group1,ou=DEFGH,ou=DEFG,ou=ABC,o=AB
groupMembership cn=group2,ou=COURSES,ou=ABC,o=AB
groupMembership cn=group3,ou=DEFGH,ou=DEFG,ou=ABC,o=AB
email                              test2@test.com
```

Here are the Liferay Control panel settings

```
Base DN :               [code]ou=ABCD,ou=ABC,o=AB
```

User Mapping

```
Authentication Search Filter : (mail=@email_address@)
Import Search Filter : (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=*))
Screen Name   :cn
Password  :sn
Email Address :mail  
Full Name   :fullName
First Name  :givenName
Middle Name  
Last Name  : sn
Job Title  :title
Portrait  
Group  : groupMembership
UUID
```

Groups

```
Import Search Filter   :  (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=*))
```

Group Mapping

```
Group Name  :company
Description  : description
User  : groupMembership
```

Its importing users but not importing user groups,
I tried setting **ldap.import.method=user** in portal-ext.properties but still its not creating/importing user groups, 
NOTE : I can able to see list of groups in Control Panel but I its not importing to Liferay
i also tried  **ldap.import.method=group**, its creating only user groups but not importing any users associated to that group

Advance thanx

Answer (score 0):

For your Group mapping, Group Name should be mapped to CN.

I am not sure what User to groupMembership is meant to be, but the only thing that makes sense is actually User : member

The attribute on the User object is groupMembership, and the attribute on the Group object is member.